# jQuery.getJSON equivalent in MooTools

Tags: ajax, mootools, mootools-events

Is there any `jQuery.getJSON()` equivalent in MooTools? I have a json file named data.json and I want to get its content by calling data.json file using MooTool. Is it possible? I tried `Request.JSON()` method but it didn't work for me. The below is my code,

```
var json_req = new Request.JSON({
    url:'../public_html/data/data.json',
    method: 'get',
    secure: true,
    data:{
        json: true
    },
    onSuccess: function (res){
        this.result = res;          
    },
    onFailure: function(){
        this.result = "failed";
    }
}).send();
```

Also from the http://demos111.mootools.net/ I found an Ajax class named Ajax() which they are widely using through out their tutorial. But in MooTools documentation I didn't find this Ajax() class. I tried to use the Ajax() by replacing my Request.JSON(), but got an "Ajax not defined" error. What is this Ajax class and how can we use it in MooTools?

Comment: What version of MooTools are you using?

Comment: I am using MooTools 1.6.0

Comment: how are you using the code? what is `this.result`? is that from other parts of your code? can you show more code so we understand how you are using Request. Request.JSON is the equivalent to jQuery.getJSON.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of the functionality you are looking after. Basically wrapping a function around the Class... you could use the Class directly also.

```
function getJSON(url, callback) {
    new Request.JSON({
        url: url,
        onSuccess: callback
    }).send();
}

// and invoque it:
getJSON('/echo/json/', function(json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

you can check it live here: https://jsfiddle.net/w64vo2vm/

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    new Request.JSON({
        url: url,
        data: {'delay': 1},
        method: 'post',
        onSuccess: function(response) {
        var myJSON = JSON.encode(response)
          console.log(myJSON); 
        }
    }).send();
})
```

You may see the result here

http://jsfiddle.net/chetabahana/qbx9b5pm/

Answer (score 0):

I have a small function for this task. Here's the code

```
var configJson;

function klak_readJson(fileurl) {
  var myRequest = new Request({
    url: fileurl,
    method: 'get',
    onRequest: function(){
      console.log('loading '+fileurl+'...');
    },
    onSuccess: function(responseText) {
      console.log('received bytes '+responseText.length);
      configJson=JSON.parse(myRequest.response.text);
    }
  });
  myRequest.send();
}
```

Call the function to store the JSON object into configJson

```
klak_readJson('/js/test.json');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why to do sync ajax? I would say that is a _no no_, synchronous requests are being deprecated around the web. Only in rare cases, the use of a synchronous method is preferable to an asynchronous one.